# How to implement different types of a class: inheritance, interface or class property?

Tags: entity-framework, oop, inheritance, interface, domain-driven-design

I need to implement the following but I'm not shure what the best way is:

I'm creating a message functionality for an MVC app.

There are two types of messages:

1. Public messages
2. Private messages

The only difference is that public messages have a ValidFrom and ValidTo date field. I have tried the following:

**Method 1, interface**
IMessage interface. Two classes PrivateMessage and PublicMessage that implements the interface. PublicMessage has the two extra properties. Mapped it to two different tables with entity framework.

**Method 2, inheritance**
Create a message base class that has all the fields. Create two classes that inherit the base class. Can map the message class to the db so I only have one table to keep the records. I cannot map an interface with EF Code First it seems.

**Method 3, Enum property to set what type of message**

```
    public enum MessageType
    {
        Public = 1,
        Private = 2,
    }
```

I just have one Message Class, but add a field to show what type of message it is. Maps easily to one table, and easy to search for messages of type "Public". I have to make a mini wrapper around the enum becouse EF wont create a field in the db for it though.

Is really the two property fields enough to justify two different classes? Searching two database tables for unread messages is a bit ineffective?

Is there a right way to do this?

I use Entity Framework Code First 4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORM frameworks usually solve the inheritance problem in three ways :
1.One table for all objects: in this approach there's one table and each concrete class will use the same table . A discriminator will be used to find out which record is related to which class.
2.One table for each concrete object: for each concrete object there will be a corresponding table in the database and each object has its own map .The framework doesn't know that these objects are part of a inheritance hierarchy.(no discriminator is needed)
3.One table for each object (concrete or abstract):in this approach shared data is stored in a table that's map to the base abstract class and each concrete object will have a separated table storing its own data and there's a one to one relationship between this table and its parent table.Again a discriminator is needed in parent table to show the framework which records belong to which object.

in first approach number of tables is minimum (just one table) but it has all the fields of all objects . thus all uncommon fields should be nullable and can accpet null.
in second shared data is distributed among many tables but each table is in control of its own fields thus there's no need to have some unnecessary null values.
The third approach has the most number of tables the shared data is stored in one place and again there's no unnecessary null values all over the place.

It seems that according to your scenario the first approach is the best because the difference between two objects is very small (only two fields) and having some null values in your table is tolerable and it's better than having two or three tables in your database,

Comment: Thanks, regarding the first approach. Would you use an interface that the two classes inherit. Do you know how to map it to the same table in EF (is it enough to set the modelBuilder.Entity<PublicMessage>().ToTable("Messages");
modelBuilder.Entity<PrivateMessage>().ToTable("Messages");?

Comment: actually I don't think you need an interface you can have two classes as PublicMessage and PrivateMessage that both are inherited from one BaseMessage.I am not a EF expert but here's an article that can help :http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very helpful. Last question, would you include all fields in the base message class or just the common fields? It seems odd to have properties on the PrivateMessage class that it does not use though, so I'm leaning towards only having the common fields.

Comment: BaseMessage should include the common fields only

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this is many ways, as it seems that you are experimenting with.  So...

1) You can have 1 entity `Message` that contains all fields and an extra column `IsPublic`
2) You can have 2 entities `PublicMessage` and `PrivateMessage` persisted in 2 tables
3) You can have TPT or TPH inheritance model where you have `Message` as a base class of `PublicMessage` and `PrivateMessage`

The question of which to use is more about what business problem you are trying to solve.  You mention that searching two tables is inefficient.  So, I assume that you have a view to build where a single person can see both private and public messages.  If you can, it is better to optimize after you have a performance issue (and data to support it).

It is interesting that the public messages have a to and from date.  This suggests that the life cycle of the two entities differ.  This could indicate that they need to be managed separately.

With all those assumptions, I would opt for the simple and make them to separate entities.  Making two queries for unread messages is not the end of the world.

Comment: Hi, you're right about the queries, it is not the biggest problem. Thinking about it there are several cases where two tables will be faster, but the one query that will run a lot is "show unread messages" kinda the same as here in StackOverflow... You're right about the life cycle. Public messages have a defined duration, so I feel it belongs in two classes. I'll try to get the ORM to map it the best way, and not let it dictate how i build the domain model.